# RecyclerView Giving error

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have two lists , one of all items and other of items which user selected. i want to change icon of items which is selected by user but getting error i do not know why.

Here is code of my RecyclerView :-

```
package adapters;

import java.util.List;

import com.qanda.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update
        extends
        RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update.MyViewHolder> {

    List<Categories> list;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<Categories> mSelectedList;
    int pos[];
    int x = 0;

    public RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update(List<Categories> list,
            Context context, List<Categories> mSelectedList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.mSelectedList = mSelectedList;
        pos = new int[list.size()];

        // capturepos();
        // Log.d("item Select List", mSelectedList.get(0).mCategory);
        // Log.d("item List", list.get(1).mCategory);
        // for(int i = 0 ; i < mSelectedList.size() ; i++){
        // Log.d("Inside Capture pos 1st loop", "hey");
        // for(int j =0 ; j < list.size() ; j++){
        // Log.d("Inside Capture pos 2nd loop", "hey");
        // if(mSelectedList.get(i).mCategory.equals(list.get(j).mCategory)){
        // pos[x] = j;
        // x++;
        // }
        // }
        // }
    }

    // public void capturepos(){
    //
    // }
    public List<Categories> getList() {
        return mSelectedList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int arg1) {
        Categories cat = list.get(arg1);
        holder.mCategory.setText(cat.mCategory);
        // holder.mIcon.setImageResource(cat.mIconId);
        for (int i = 0; i < pos.length; i++) {
            if (arg1 == pos[i]) {
                holder.mAddIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup arg0, int arg1) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cust_row_recyclerview_categories,
                arg0, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView mIcon, mAddIcon;
        TextView mCategory;
        int i = 1;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cateogry_text);
            mAddIcon = (ImageView) itemView
                    .findViewById(R.id.category_select_icon);
            mAddIcon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (i % 2 == 1) {
                        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                                R.drawable.settrans);
                        mAddIcon.startAnimation(anim);
                        mAddIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
                        i++;
                //      Categories cat = new Categories();
                //      cat.mCategory = mCategory.getText().toString();
                //      mSelectedList.add(cat);
                    } else {
                        Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context,
                                R.drawable.settrans);
                        mAddIcon.startAnimation(anim);
                        mAddIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add_black_24dp);
                        i++;
                //      Categories cat = new Categories();
                //      cat.mCategory = mCategory.getText().toString();
                //      mSelectedList.remove(cat);

                    }
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

My RecyclerView is showing only full list without any changes. What i did is inside constructor commented.
When i try to print items in log

```
07-15 18:03:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(7610): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
07-15 18:03:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:255)
07-15 18:03:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:308)
07-15 18:03:25.173: E/AndroidRuntime(7610):     at adapters.RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update.<init>(RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update.java:40)
```

Comment: please share your error logs

Comment: @Kushan It do not give any error but when trying to print item in log , it gives the error mentioned above

Comment: your passed mItemSelectedList is empty. thus calling // Log.d("item Select List", mSelectedList.get(0).mCategory); throws the exception. There is no position 0

Comment: @Kushan its showing the same error to list also , but its working fine

Comment: yes that works because at the list is empty only at line 40 and you try to access the 0th index. Later you are adding stuff to it. Thus it will later have a 0th position item. It is only empty when you call 40th line of your code

Comment: why you are putting loop inside the onBindViewHolder ??

Answer (score 0):

your passed `mItemSelectedList` is empty.
thus calling

```
  Log.d("item Select List", mSelectedList.get(0).mCategory); //line 40
```

throws the exception. There is no position 0. Thus trying to print it inside the log is trying to get a non existent position index 0 inside this list

```
package adapters;

import java.util.List;

import com.qanda.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update
    extends
       RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update.MyViewHolder> {

List<Categories> list;
//bad idea to pass a context, can lead to memory leaks




public RecyclerView_Adapter_Categories_update(List<Categories> list        ) {
           this.list = list;
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Categories cat = list.get(position);
    holder.mCategory.setText(cat.mCategory);

    holder.mAddIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

      public void onClick(View v){

        holder.mAddIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_done_black_24dp);
        //secondSelectedList.add(cat)
        //selectedListAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        //this will change the icon in first list and add it to your second list if your adapter is set.
      }

   });


}

@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.cust_row_recyclerview_categories,parent, false);

    return new MyViewHolder(view);
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    ImageView mIcon, mAddIcon;
    TextView mCategory;


    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mCategory = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cateogry_text);
        mAddIcon = (ImageView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.category_select_icon);

    }

}

}
```

Comment: its showing the same error to list also , but its working fine

Comment: yes that works because at the list is empty only at line 40 and you try to access the 0th index. Later you are adding stuff to it. Thus it will later have a 0th position item. It is only empty when you call 40th line of your code

Comment: Whats the solution then? Where should i put my algo to?

Comment: Here check out the solution. Let me know if you run into any errors :)

Comment: No dude. u got it wrong. i have two lists , one that user selected in previous list and one full list. i want the items which user selected previously should have other icon and rest other

Comment: Sorry man, i would not know what you need as i only have a part of your code. Anyway in the onclick, add the Category at list.get(position) to the List which your other selected adapter has. do a notifyDataSetChanged(). the selected item should then appear in your other list if it has a proper adapter set